# use rosserial with FastSerial.h (ArduIMU)

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to modify the arduimu driver to publish imu messages via rosserial but my problem is that arduimu uses FastSerial.h which is required to be included before HardwareSerial.h, but I can't include FastSerial.h before ros.h because FastSerial.h defines HardwareSerial_h which then cuases HardwareSerial.h not to be included within ros.h and therefore fails to compile.
Does anyone have an idea on how to make rosserial work in combination with FastSerial.h?
I tried replacing HardwareSerial with FastSerial in ros_lib's ArduinoHardware.h and it compiled but doesn't work (when trying to connect using `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB1` it loses sync with the device and no topics are being published).

Thanks,
Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40080/use-rosserial-with-fastserial.h-(arduimu)/) by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) on ROS Answers with karma: 360 on 2012-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved it by using arduimu v1.7 instead of v1.8 which isn't using FastSerial.h ... and maybe the fix with replacing HardwareSerial with FastSerial works because I'm still getting the same sync loss using v1.7 when I don't comment some of the imu related commands out.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) with karma: 360 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0